# Remove text formatting on paste in WPF RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, richtextbox

vs2010, WPF .NET 4.5 here.

I have a `RichTextBox` in my view. The text is set to Arial, size 12:

```
    <xctk:RichTextBox  DataContext="{StaticResource EditorViewModel}" Grid.Row="1" 
        Height="296" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True"       Margin="6,145,6,0" 
        Name="richTextBoxArticleBody"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="962" Grid.RowSpan="2"  
        BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="1" AcceptsTab="True" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="12"
        Text="{Binding PastedText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

I want to strip all formatting from a paste into my `RichTextBox`. I have a Paste button in my view which is bound to a  `FormatPastedText` command:

```
 private void FormatPastedTextCommandAction()
    {
        string paste = (string)Clipboard.GetData("Text");

        Clipboard.SetText(paste);

        PastedText += paste.ToString();

        Clipboard.Clear();          
    }
```

This almost works except the the pasted text is not displayed in font size 12 but rather in around 15. Typed text is formatted at size 12 as expected. Is there any better way to go about this or a way of setting the font size of the pasted string?

Thanks

Comment: paste is of type string. You need not use paste.ToString().

Comment: Try Clipboard.GetText() instead of Clipboard.GetData("Text"). This may fix your issue.

Comment: Yeah these were just bits of code I forgot to change. Same result...

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this may be fix your issues. This may not fix the issue. But there are some improvements to the code mentioned as comment in the code.

```
private void FormatPastedTextCommandAction()
    {
        string paste = Clipboard.GetText();     // casting is not required if this function is used

        // Clipboard.SetText(paste);            // This line is reduntant

        PastedText += paste;                    // no need to call ToString()

        // Clipboard.Clear();                      // You should not clear the Clipboard, as the user may want to paste the data in some other window/application.
    }
```

Comment: No, I need to clear the clipboard else the un-formatted copy is appended to the string. No, I need to address the size of the pasted string...

Comment: On further inspection it looks like this is something to do with the pasted text not being inserted to the RTB in RTF format...

Answer (score 0):

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.KeyCode == Keys.V) && e.Control && !e.Alt && !e.Shift)
    {
        // remove text formatting in the text in clipboard
        if (Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.Html) || Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.Rtf))
        {
            string plainText = Clipboard.GetText();
            Clipboard.Clear();
            Clipboard.SetText(plainText);
        }
    }
}
```